# Scenario vs Scenario Outline

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I need to write out a test scenario in SpecFlow with C# where:

```
Log In Test

I select a store from a list in Screen A
Perform tests in the store on Screen B
Go back to Store Select in Screen A
Select Second store from list 
Perform Test on store. 
Log Out
```

I am currently using a Scenario Outline with variable for each store off a list but that does not seem to work for me. Any ideas would be helpful?

Comment: what *that does not seem to work for me* means?

Comment: Have you defined the steps? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Also, `Scenario Outline` requires `Examples:` in which you provide a table for each value. You then reference each variable via `<variable name>` in your test

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding it fully. Can I organize the scenario log in | Scenario Outline | Store Select | Store Tests. This is currently how it is organized. How do I get the scenario outline to loop tests for each store.

Comment: I am currently using a variable name for the search box of the store.

Answer (score 3):

Your test is missing a few crucial things:

1. You're not defining whether or not it's a scenario or scenario outline.
2. There is no 'Given', 'When' or 'Then' step
3. You need an `Examples:` block when working with a scenario outline.

Here's what your test should look like for a scenario:

```
Scenario: Log In Test

Given I have setup my database // Put any 'setup code' here
When I select a store from a list in Screen A // Put your 'action' here
Then Screen A should display item number 5 // Assert your 'action' does what is expected
```

Now, for outlines, you can run the test multiple times for different arguments.
For example, the above test could be written like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Log In Test

Given I have setup my database
When I select a store from a list in <ScreenName>
Then <ScreenName> should display item number <ItemNumber>

Examples: 
| ScreenName | ItemNumber |
| Screen A   | 5          |
| Screen B   | 53         |
| Screen C   | 9874       |
```

Comment: could I write tests below the Scenario Outline that would be repeated by the Scenario Outline test @Rob

Comment: @Arsenii What do you mean? The test will be run once for each row in examples

Comment: Can I add more tests below the Scenario Outline test when I am in the store. Ideally I want to select a store run some tests. When the tests are done move on to the next store on the the list. Would I be able to add in Scenario tests below the Scenario Outline test?

Comment: can I place more tests below the test scenario for them to be cycled through?

Comment: @Arsenii No, you can't - and you shouldn't. Tests should be independent and quite specific as to what you're testing. DRY doesn't apply to tests so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run tests for more then one variable then what you need is a scenario outline.
Lets say you to test a login page with various versions of invalid email and passwords, your feature file will look like this:

> Feature: Name of the feature file
>   Scenario Outline: Brief explanation of the story
>   Given User clicks login
>   When Enters "email" and "password"
>   Then Error message must be seen

*Examples*:

```
| email             | password                          |  
| en email          | a password                        |
```